# Java ImageJ - how to make an image transparent?

Tags: java, image, transparency, rgb, imagej

I'd ask, how can I make an image transparent?

Actually, I tried to read RGB Values from IndexColorModel

```
ImageProcessor ip1 = img1.getProcessor();
IndexColorModel indexColor = (IndexColorModel)ip1.getColorModel();
```

then read a parameters wich i need to create new IndexColorModel

```
int pixelBits = indexColor .getPixelSize();

int mapSize = cm.getMapSize();
byte[] reds = new byte[mapSize];
cm.getReds(reds);

byte[] greens = new byte[mapSize];
cm.getGreens(greens);

byte[] blues = new byte[mapSize];
cm.getBlues(blues);
```

and create new IndexColorModel and set it to another ImagePlus with different transparentIndex

```
indexColor = new IndexColorModel(pixelBits, MapSize, reds, greens, blues, transparentIndex );
ImageProcessor ip3;
ip3.setColorModel(indexColor);
```

but this is wrong idea...

Should I use IndexColorModel with cmap and hasAlpha parameters? How can I do this?

Thank you in advance for help!

Answer (score 3):

> I'd ask, how can I make an image transparent?

That is too much work to make an image transparent. For a input `image` of type `BufferedImage` I would just do:

1. Create a new temporary `BufferedImage` `tmpImage` with the same size to `image` and type: `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB`
2. Get it's graphics of the `tmpImage` and convert it to `Graphics2D` by up-casting.
3. set alpha composite to the Graphics2D instance with the transparency level i need
4. Draw the image and get done with it.

For example:

```
   BufferedImage tmpImg = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), 
                                                  BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
   Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) tmpImg.getGraphics();
   g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.SrcOver.derive(0.5f)); 
            // set the transparency level in range 0.0f - 1.0f 
   g2d.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
   image = tmpImg;
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. I need to use ImageProcessor because of ImageJ stack to show resul but with BufferedImage it's impossible, am i right?